# Wordpress - Adding javascript to head on successful submission of contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am trying to write a plugin that allows me to output HTML or Javascript to the head section of my page when a user successfully submits a Contact Form 7.
I have tried using wpcf7_before_send_mail, but am having no success.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add to Additional Settings field of Contact Form (official doc shows redirect http://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/)

```
on_sent_ok: "customFunction();"
```

and then do whatever you want in that function

```
<script>
  function customFunction() {

  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response on this, much appreciated